# How to use multiple numbers in SelectInput in Shiny

Tags: r, filter, datatable, shiny, dplyr

I have a question regarding Shiny and the SelectInput function. This is my selectinput right now:

```
 selectInput("top1", label = h3("TOP500"),
                     c("TRUE" = 1,
                       "FALSE" = 0,
                       "BOTH" = 0|1), selected = 0)
```

I used it for the following function:

```
filter(sales_category_id == input$top1)
```

This is a table who gets mutated by dplyr and in the end i want to choose between sales_category_id 0,1 or both.

Can someone please help me out? This is not working and everything i tried did not give me the correct result.

First question by the way, so if i wrote something unclear please let me know :)

EDIT:

Since the id can only be 0 or 1 i fixed it this way:

```
selectInput("top1", label = h3("TOP500"),
                     c("TRUE" = 0,
                       "FALSE" = 1,
                       "BOTH" = 2), selected = 0)

filter(sales_category_id != input$top1
```

I am still intrested in an answer though.

Comment: A selectinput might not be the best method to go about this. Have you considered group check box input?

Comment: I did consider but i still don't believe it is impossible with selectinput.

Answer (score 0):

```
                        selectInput("top1", label = h5("TOP500"),
                     c("TRUE" = 1,
                       "FALSE" = 0,
                       "BOTH" = "BOTH"), selected = "BOTH") 

    filter(if (input$top1 == 1) sales_category_id %in% 1 
           else if (input$top1 == 0) sales_category_id %in% 0 
           else sales_category_id %in% c(0:100)) %>%
```

This is my best solution in the end :)